# Multiple VPC's with same CIDR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have to create multiple VPC (one for each application). I tried creating another VPC with same CIDR 10.0.0.0/16 and is working fine.

So is it ok to create multiple VPC with same CIDR's?

Also I am trying to host a [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) application which includes a webserver and a RDS server.

Answer (score 13):

As long as machines in your VPCs will **never** need to communicate with machines in the other VPC, this is fine.

However, when you have all of the RFC1918 space available to you, why would you choose to use the same subnet? Use 10.1.0.0/16 or something for the second VPC. It is so simple to choose a different VPC, that it's very much worth doing so that your machines can communicate if the need arises at some point in the future.